# How to render PDF without use respond_to format.pdf in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, render, prawn

How can I render send to a client a file (PDF, CSV, etc) without render this file?

For example, imagine a Students controller (created using scaffold), we have 'new' form and 'create' action:

```
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Student created'
        format.html { redirect_to(@student) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

When a student is successfully created it will redirect to 'show' template. That is OK!
But I need to send to client -for example- a PDF file and then render 'show' action.

This PDF file is like a creation receipt for client.

Extra info: now use Prawn to make PDF and sending to client by code like this:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { render :layout => false }
    end
```

In brief, I need get filled form, create student, send PDF to browser (as a creation receipt) and render 'show' action to display student created.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you're looking for, you want to show he "show.html.erb" file to the user but you also want the user to download a static PDF file with other details?

Comment: Yes.
How I use redirect_to format.pdf to send a PDF to client, but I want to sned this and show immediately 'show.html.erb'.

Comment: You can't do two renders (a pdf and a page) at a time in a controller. Either ou send the pdf, or you render another page.

Comment: @apneadiving, Thank you very much for your answer. I know that I can call only one render or redirect, but this is the goal of my question: How can I send this PDF and show this page?

Comment: Send PDF == render 1. show page == render 2. Can't do both in one go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution using wicked_pdf.

This creates the pdf but doesn't download it.  Saves PDF to a file. Saves the link in the database, rerenders the view with the link displayed (view is displaying the @plan).

```
    # create a unique PDF filename
    pdf_uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s
    pdf_uuid_filename = Rails.root.join('public/pdf', "#{pdf_uuid}.pdf").to_s

    # create a pdf but don't display it
    pdf_file = render_to_string :pdf => pdf_uuid_filename, 
                                :template  => 'plans/show.pdf.erb' ,
                                :layout    => 'pdf',
                                :save_only => true
    # save to a file
    File.open(pdf_uuid_filename, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf_file
    end
    # create full URL path to created file  
    @plan.url = request.url[0, request.url.index("plans")] +  'pdf/' + CGI::escape("#{pdf_uuid}.pdf")
    @plan.save!
    # render the page again with the link being displayed
    redirect_to :back
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, by far is to just display a link to the PDF on the show page. 
But if you really want to do both in one step you could do it using Javscript and the ':inline => false' option for prawnto.

make sure your prawnto options has **:inline => false** this will force the PDF request to render as download attachemnt not a view.

```
prawnto :prawn => {
          :left_margin => 48, 
          :right_margin => 48,
          :top_margin => 24,
          :bottom_margin => 24,
          :inline => false}
```

then at the bottom of your show.html.erb view point the window to the pdf version using JS.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    window.location=<%=url_for :action=>"show", :format=>:pdf%>;

</script>
```

This will show the normal html view and then a download dialog popup will show asking the user to save the PDF but will not redirect the user away from the show.html page.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a a pdf to the user you can make a link available in your rendered view upon successful form submission. Then the user can click on the link and download and view the pdf. Or if you want to display the pdf without the user having to download it you can use a pdf web reader: take a look at http://www.scribd.com/ and ttp://crocodoc.com/, both offer the ability to upload a pdf to their servers and to allow your web user to see it using their viewer.

Hope this help.

Comment: if you feel this is your answer could you mark it as such? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Matteo-Melani, but I'm trying to looking for other ideas.